# How to install packages/programs from sunfreeware to home directory without root access

Tags: emacs, solaris

I on solaris 10 and I wanted to install the latest version of emacs.
I don't have root access. I tried compiling emacs 23.4 from source and I am struck due to an old version of compiler in my system.

I am trying to use the per-built binary from sunfreeware.com, Is there a means to install it in my home directory without root access?

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible for most packages as long as their binaries support to be relocated.

You first need to convert the pkg files to their filesystem variant with `pkgtrans`, then, in most cases, you also need to extract the embedded archive which is just a cpio file.

Finally, you will need to adjust file permissions using the `prototype` file and possibly tweak some files or environment variables like `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to have the program or libraries be functional.

Of course this can become quite cumbersome when you have to repeat all of this for every dependency the initial package might have.

I don't know about `emacs` but I suspect it to have many dependencies so the technique I suggest here might be too complex to worth the effort, especially as `emacs` has an alternative which is always installed and that many people prefer, I mean of course `vi`.